# If a $p$ is prime number, for some $p$ ,fraction $1/p$ ,is decimal is $p-1$ period repetition, can anyone prove it?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

If a $p$ is prime number, for some $p$, fraction $1/p$, is  decimal is $p-1$  period repetition,can anyone prove it?

For example $\frac17=0.14285714$   you can see period repetition  is 6
and so on it  is continued
for $\frac1{19}  =0.05263157894736842105263$ period  repetition is $p-1=18$

It is not true for all prime number, for example, for  11 and 5 it's  not true. I want to prove prime number like 7,19 is continued to infinite

Where can I find a proof of this that these number to infinite there are.

Thanks for reply.

Comment: you mean like for $p=2$ or like $p=3$ or $p=5$ ? in these cases they don't have a period repeatation or of the wrong length. What exactly is your question?

Comment: yes, i talked for some prime numbers,not all numbers,like 19,7 i want to know  there is a proof  that talk the prime number like 7,19 that has repeatation is continued to infinite

Comment: Period of length $p-1$ occurs, iff $10$ is a primitive root modulo $p$.  AFAIK it is not known whether this happens for infinitely many primes. This is related to [Artin's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin's_conjecture_on_primitive_roots).

Comment: thanks but  i need proof,is it possible that i prove this>,i..e. we have infinite prime number like 7,19

Comment: It is believed that there are infinitely many such primes. But no one on our site is smarter than Artin. So, No proof!

Comment: For $p$ not equal to $2$ or $5$, the expansion is periodic, and the period divides $p-1$. That is the simplest general result.

Comment: thanks for reply,so bad ,so we should forget it!

Comment: for p 11,2,5 and .....is not true

Comment: But if you are just interested in showing there *exists** $p$ such that the period is $p-1$, your example of $7$ is good, and it is not hard to write down a formal proof that the decimal expansion does have period $6$.

Comment: i want to prove general case  and not be Special case .this proof is important for solving next problem.it is a dream

Comment: André Nicolas please explain your method proof,thanks for attention to my question.

Answer (score 0):

There's  number theory theorem that states $a^{p-1} = 1 mod( p)$ (Fermat's theorem).[Assuming p doesn't divide a]  So $10^{p-1} = 1 mod (p)$. [This won't hold for p=2 and p=5 because 2 and 5 divide 10].  So if you divide 1 by p you will  get a 1 in the p- 1  reiteration.  So if this is the first one, the period is p-1.  If this isn't the first 1 then the period divides p-1.

A more basic explanation is that when you divide p into 1 you get a remainder.  When you divide p into that you get another. There are only p-1 possible remainders (other than 0) so eventually you have to repeat remainders (or come to a 0 and stop).  When you repeat you cycle through so *at most* the cycle is p-1.  That doesn't explain why if the cycle is less than p-1 then it divides p-1, however.

Comment: thanks for reply,it is good think,i will study more deep and i comment the my result.